# What is the workflow to build and debug Cordova Plugin?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to build Cordova plugin that will expose native API to Cordova JS. The plugin will not be published to the public registry.

I'll like to understand what are the tools and flow to use to develop that?
The `cordova` tool has only the ability to add/remove/ls plugin, how should I start a new plugin?

I've try to use [don/cordova-plugin-hello](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello) but when I try to modify the native implementation of ios and rebuild the project the result XCode project implementation is not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use xcode for iOS plugins and eclipse for android plugins

These are the steps I follow:

1. I create a new cordova project using the cordova CLI.
2. I open the project from eclipse/xcode
3. I create the native files for the plugin (`.m/.h` for ios, `.java` for android)
4. I create the common `.js` on the www folder and link it in the index.html
5. Finally, I add this to the `config.xml`

   `<feature name="PluginName">
       <param name="ios-package" value="iOSPluginClassName" />
       <param name="android-package" value="androidPluginClassNameIncludingPackage" />
   </feature>`

Comment: Thanks  the problem I have is when I change the native impl and user cordova run ios it does not update the xcode project

Comment: This only solve part of the workflow: this only help in debug while changing the plugin native implementation but not when changing the JavaScript wrapper.

Comment: If you want to get the changes form the javascript you have to do a "cordova prepare" or you can work directly on the Staging folder while woring from xcode, but don't forget to copy the changes to the root www folder, because the Staging folder is overwritten when you run from the CLI